# isdigit() is not evaluating to true in C

Tags: c

I am trying for half an hour now without success...
It must be so simple, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong: `isdigit()` is not evaluating to `true`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

main()
{

int a = 2;

if  (isdigit(a)) 
{   
   printf("\ncorrect\n");
}
else
{
    printf("\nnot correct\n");
}//end if


}// end main
```

I tried all things that came to my mind

```
if  (isdigit(a) == true) 
if  (isdigit(a) != false) 
if  (isdigit(a) != 0) 
if  (isdigit(a) == 1)
if  (isdigit(2)) 
if  (isdigit(2) == 2)
if  (isdigit(2) == true)
```

without success ...
Note: It compiles for sure, I made sure by inserting various different print statements.

Comment: "isdigit()" is intended for *ASCII characters*, not binary integers.  `isdigit('2') == true`; `isdigit(2) == false`

Comment: @paulsm4 `isdigit()` is intended for all `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  C11 7.4.1 In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I just realize what a bad example this is, but I got the answers I wanted and now understand the `isdigit()` function, thx to al;

Comment: @paulsm4: More specifically it is intended for determining whether the specified character represents a digit in the *current locale* in the *execution character set*.

Comment: Do not compare the result of `isdigit()` for equality to *anything*. If the argument is a digit, it returns some *arbitrary* non-zero (i.e., true) result. Just use it directly as a condition (as you've already done). And make sure the argument is either within the range of `unsigned char` or equal to `EOF` (the latter isn't particularly useful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `int a = 2;` to `char a = '2';`Or `int a = '2';`See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/)

Comment: thx for all the good answers, I had to make a choice here to accept one out of the many...

Comment: It was thin pickings to find any quality answers to your question.  This one wouldn't have been my first choice.

Comment: Most of the answers were really good. I liked about this one that it pointed out that it can be either `char a = '2';` or `int a = '2';` which comes in handy when using `scanf();`

Comment: Please note that the argument passed to the `isdigit()` macro (and all the other type-check macros) is supposed to be of type `int`, and the _value_ is expected to fit in an `unsigned char`. Note also that `char` may be a signed type on some systems. (And that character literals are positive values of type `int`).

Answer (score 7):

You misunderstood the usage of `isdigit`.

```
int a = '2';
isdigit(a);
```

If you pass a number to it, say `isdigit(2)`, it takes `2` as the code for a character in the character set of the current locale (eg. ASCII code `2` is `STX`, START OF THE TEXT, which is obviously not a digit number).

Comment: `isdigit`'s prototype is actually `int isdigit(int);`.

Comment: The prototypes for all the `iswhatever()` family of functions take an `int` parameter.  The fact that you tend to implicitly cast `char` to `int` when you use it is co-incidental.

Comment: `isdigit` interprets its argument as a code for a character in the character set of the current locale, not necessarily ASCII.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the more precise explanation. I updated and improved my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`isdigit()` indicates whether the value of the argument represents an ASCII digit; that is, it is in the range 48 through 57. See the reference chart [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/).

So `isdigit(2)` correctly returns 0, since the integer value 2 is not in the range.

If you change your code to `isdigit('2')` then you will get the result you expect, because the value of the ASCII character `2` is 50.

Answer (score 1):

You have `int` 2. It doesn't represent character "2"
2 as character is just "Start of text" character (not a digit)

You need

```
isdigit('2')
```

Comment: `'2'` is an `int` too

Comment: What makes the character with ASCII value 2 'unreadable'?  It is a control character, yes...  But it is still has a symbol, which looks like this: `☻`.  The only truth here is that it's not a digit.

Comment: @paddy I believe control characters are not usually displayed. I can't see how "Start of text" is symbol you post.

Comment: @Paddy Corrected to be more precise

Answer (score -3):

Remove the isdigit.
simply write:-

```
if((a))
printf("correct");

else
printf("wrong");
```

Comment: how is this supposed to solve the problem? my code snippet is only symbolic, of course I don't just want to test if the variable has a value or not...